# Scraping font-size from HTML and CSS

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the font-size of each section of text in an HTML page. I have spent the past few days trying to do it, but I feel like I am trying to re-invent the wheel. I have looked at python libraries like cssutils, beautiful-soup, but haven't had much luck sadly. I have made my own html parser that finds the font size inside the html only, but it doesn't look at stylesheets which is really important. Any tips to get me headed in the right direction?

Comment: This is going to be very, very hard to do, since font size can be set dynamically based on the viewport size, CSS media type, and so on -- you'll effectively have to render the page and check the font size.

Comment: This is essentially impossible to do *correctly*. There might be client side rendering in Javascript that changes this. Depending on why you want to do this, you have different alternatives. If you're trying to use this to determine the importance of text, you're better off using the HTML tags themselves. If you really *really* want the font size, you're going to have to use something like Phantom.js or selenium with it's Python bindings.

Comment: @ChristianTernus couldn't I just use a default viewport size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selenium with firefox or phantomjs if you're on a headless machine, the browser will render the page, then you can locate the element and get it's attributes.

On python the method to get attributes is self explanatory, `Element_obj.get_attribute('attribute_name')`

Comment: Selenium is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried it with chrome and it worked but it was painfully slow. Now working on getting it to work with Firefox. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If speed is what you're looking for and don't mind not seeing the test progress I recommend PhantomJS, it is a full browser without the user interface and it is pretty fast. It works out-of-the-box, just need to install and have the executable path on the PATH environment variable.